# How to create and populate SwiftUI list with Firebase data?

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, swiftui

I need to build a SwiftUI list using a separated string from a Firebase Realtime Database. Using `.observeSingleEvent`, I successfully got the string from the database, separated it and put it in a `String` array. At the time being, the only problem is I can't get the array to properly take the separated `String` array value, as the async data from Firebase doesn't load in time for the view to acknowledge it. What mistakes am I encountering?

Thanks.

```
@State var syList: [String] = ["1", "2", "3"]

func observeSymptomList(completion: @escaping ([String]) -> Void) {

    var symptomsArray: [String] = [""]

    let ref = Database.database().reference().child("symptoms")

    ref.observeSingleEvent(of: .value, with: { (snapshot) in

        if let value = snapshot.value as? String {
            print(value)
            symptomsArray = value.components(separatedBy: ", ")
            print(symptomsArray)
        }
        else { completion(["error"]) }

    }) { (error) in
        print(error.localizedDescription)}

    print(symptomsArray)
    completion(symptomsArray)
}

var body: some View {
    VStack {
        List {
            Section(header: ListHeader()) {
                ForEach(syList, id: \.self) {sy in
                    Text(sy)
                }
            }

        }.onAppear {
            self.observeSymptomList { (name) in
                self.syList = name
            }
        }
        .listStyle(GroupedListStyle())
    }
    .navigationBarTitle("Stil de viață")
    .navigationBarBackButtonHidden(true)
}
```

Comment: I'd generally recommend extracting data access logic into a view model, and using `@ObservableObject`, `@Published`, and `@ObservedObject` to manage state. The code in [this article](https://peterfriese.dev/swiftui-firebase-fetch-data/) might be useful (it's for Firestore, but should easy to adapt to RTDB).

Comment: must see when it comes to data and SwiftUI https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2019/226/

Answer (score 0):

You are calling your completion handler before you're receiving the data from firebase. You should place your completion handler after you assigned values to `symptomsArray` like this:

```
func observeSymptomList(completion: @escaping ([String]) -> Void) {
  var symptomsArray: [String] = [""]

  let ref = Database.database().reference().child("symptoms")

  ref.observeSingleEvent(of: .value, with: { (snapshot) in
    if let value = snapshot.value as? String {
      print(value)
      symptomsArray = value.components(separatedBy: ", ")
      completion(symptomsArray) // <-- move this statement here
      print(symptomsArray)
    }
    else { 
      completion(["error"]) 
    }
  }) { (error) in
    print(error.localizedDescription)}
    print(symptomsArray)
}
```